# SUMPRODUCT & ROUND

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010, rounding

According to [superuser.com/questions](https://superuser.com/questions/905298/sumproduct-round?newreg=744de92b63544651b748f163f8739517)

How can get the conditioned product of the two below arrays in the formula ( `[DSW_INCLUDED] * Salary[InsuranceMultiplier]` ) to **round up** before summing?

```
=ROUND(SUMPRODUCT(([DSW_INCLUDED])*(Salary[Year]=Salary[@Year])*(Salary[Month]=Salary[@Month])*(Salary[InsuranceSituation]="Insured")*([DSW_LISTNO]=[@[DSK_LISTNO]]),(Salary[InsuranceMultiplier]))
```

As `Salary[InsuranceMultiplier] < 1`

Comment: Sample data together with expected results would help this question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> <sub>How can get the conditioned product of the two below arrays in the formula (...) to **round up** before summing?</sub>

Perhaps change ROUND to ROUNDUP and bring it into the cyclic calculation rather rounding the result.

```
=SUMPRODUCT((Salary[Year]=Salary[@Year])*(Salary[Month]=Salary[@Month])*(Salary[InsuranceSituation]="Insured")*([DSW_LISTNO]=[@[DSK_LISTNO]]),
            ROUNDUP([DSW_INCLUDED], 0), ROUNDUP(Salary[InsuranceMultiplier], 0))
'alternate
=SUMPRODUCT((Salary[Year]=Salary[@Year])*(Salary[Month]=Salary[@Month])*(Salary[InsuranceSituation]="Insured")*([DSW_LISTNO]=[@[DSK_LISTNO]]),
            ROUNDUP([DSW_INCLUDED]*Salary[InsuranceMultiplier], 0))
```

Comment: `=SUMPRODUCT((Salary[Year]=Salary[@Year])*(Salary[Month]=Salary[@Month])*(Salary[InsuranceSituation]="Insured")*([DSW_LISTNO]=[@[DSK_LISTNO]]), ROUNDUP([DSW_INCLUDED], 0), ROUNDUP(Salary[InsuranceMultiplier], 0))` not work, because we need rounding after production. (Example: `InsuranceMultiplier=0.1` and `DSW_INCLUDED=1200046`. In first part of answer return 0!, but the true result is: `ROUNDUP(120004.6)=120005`;  indeed the alternate is true and works.